# Left join the result of subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I would like to do the following and it is not working. I would like to left join the result of a subquery.

```
select result1.id, result.name from (select cust.id as id, cust.name as name, ss.sold_date as soldDate, pp.product_name as productName from customers cust
left join sales ss on ss.customer_id = cust.id
left join products pp on pp.id = ss.product_id) as result
left join result as result1 on result.id = result1.id
```

When I do this, it says table 'result' does not exist. How do I left join the result alias?

Comment: First, let me make it clear. Are you trying to join subquery with itself?

Comment: @ekochergin Yes,, that's right. Is that possible at all? Assume the subquery result is a table with the data I need. I then need to self join the subquery result table to do some operations such as count, sum, etc. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: can you show what it is that you want to do with "count, sum, etc"? it's not clear to me how you would need a self-join of a subquery to do any of that.  but if you do, you would use a common table expression for that

Comment: please show the output of `select version();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment you're trying to join the subquery result with itself.

In this particular case it does not make any sense because you'll just get the same data twice. So, using the subquery once will work

```
select result1.id, result.name 
  from (select cust.id as id, cust.name as name, ss.sold_date as soldDate, pp.product_name as productName 
          from customers cust
          left join sales ss on ss.customer_id = cust.id
          left join products pp on pp.id = ss.product_id) as result
  left join result as result1 on result.id = result1.id
```

I general, if you need to use same sub-query twice, you may use a CTE (common-table-expression):

```
with sub_q as (select cust.id as id, cust.name as name, ss.sold_date as soldDate, pp.product_name as productName 
          from customers cust
          left join sales ss on ss.customer_id = cust.id
          left join products pp on pp.id = ss.product_id)

select *
  from sub_q res
  left join sub_q res1
    on res.id = res1.id
```

The CTE (the "with" part of the query above) is like a variable. In "usual" programming languages variable is being used to store values, whereas in query language it's job to store queries

UPD. The OP appeared to be on mysql version prior to 8.0 and the db OP is on doesn't support CTEs

So, here you may end up using views for example

First, a script to creaate a view

```
create view sub_q as select cust.id as id, cust.name as name, ss.sold_date as soldDate, pp.product_name as productName 
          from customers cust
          left join sales ss on ss.customer_id = cust.id
          left join products pp on pp.id = ss.product_id;
```

Second, run the query

```
select *
  from sub_q res
  left join sub_q res1
    on res.id = res1.id;
```

Alternatively you may repeat subquery twice in the select statement

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For some reason, I tried this and getting syntax errors.
select result1.id, result.name 
  with sub_q as (select cust.id as id, cust.name as name, ss.sold_date as soldDate, pp.product_name as productName 
          from customers cust
          left join sales ss on ss.customer_id = cust.id
          left join products pp on pp.id = ss.product_id) 
select *
  from sub_q result
  left join sub_q result1
    on result.id = result1.id

Comment: @user3376592 the "with" part goes first before any "select". Just like I did it in the second example of my answer

Comment: I tried that as well. It looks like with is only supported for mysql versions prior to 8.0. Any other alternative?

Comment: @user3376592 what version are you on?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Heidisql version 11

Comment: @user3376592, HeidiSQL is the client. The database is mysql. What version?

Comment: Oh yeah the database version is 6.0

Comment: please show the output of `select version();`

Comment: @user3376592 you're right CTEs are not supported prior to 8.0. In my updated answer I suggest you to create and use a view instead

Comment: or upgrade to 8 or to mariadb; it won't be much longer before < 8 is no longer supported

Comment: @ekochergin You are a genius. Thanks for your help.